# PowerBuilder catch retrieve ORA

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

How to convert a standard error message to my own message?
I have this code:

```
dw_1.setSqlSelect('SELECT * , FROM TABLE1)
dw_1.retrieve()
```

I know about comma in select! User write select, so he can make mistakes.
I don't want standard Error like "ORA-xxxx, syntax ~~" but I want my own error.

How to do that?

```
Try
dw_1.retrieve()
Catch (DWRuntimeError myExc)
       MessageBox ("DWRuntimeError", "Errortext")
End Try
```

Doesn't work, I have error in line 'dw_1.retrieve()'.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use the datawindows `dberror` event for this. There you find everything you need in the paramater list. Here is a detailed description of it:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37783_1150/html/dwref/CAIECBBA.htm

Have a nice day!

Regards Gábor